# Python: Making a standalone executable file on MacOS with py2app

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, executable, py2app

I have an application in a python script `my_app.py` and want to make a standalone executable out of it on a MacOS (10.14). Following the video-tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4ykDbciXa8), I entered sequentially the following commmands:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv --system-site-packages
source venv/bin/activate
pip install py2app
cd /path/to/my_app.py
python setup.py py2app -A
```

with the following `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ["my_app.py"]
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    "argv_emulation": True,
    "packages": ["certifi"],
}
setup(
    app = APP,
    data_files = DATA_FILES,
    options = {"py2app": OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ["py2app"]

)
```

but got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    setup_requires = ["py2app"]
  File "/Users/mymac/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 984, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/Users/mymac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/Users/mymac/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 567, in finalize_options
    if isinstance(self.plist, plistlib.Dict):
AttributeError: module 'plistlib' has no attribute 'Dict'
```

With that error message, I found that [github page](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#macos) and typed the following code:

```
brew install qt  # will install qt-5.x.x
brew install libxml2
make qt5py3
python3 labelImg.py
python3 labelImg.py [IMAGE_PATH] [PRE-DEFINED CLASS FILE]

As a side note, if mssing pyrcc5 or lxml, try
pip3 install pyqt5 lxml
```

However after entering the line `make qt5py3`, I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `qt5py3'.  Stop.
```

I also tried the following commands:

```
brew install python3
pip install pipenv
pipenv --three
pipenv shell
pip install py2app
pip install PyQt5 lxml
make qt5py3
rm -rf build dist
python setup.py py2app -A
mv "dist/labelImg.app" /Applications
```

But also got

```
make: *** No rule to make target `qt5py3'.  Stop.
```

after entering the line `make qt5py3`

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/issues/322) on github

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plistlib.Dict` was available but not documented. In python 3.4 it was finally [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/plistlib.html#plistlib.writePlistToBytes); also documented that it's deprecated since 3.0.

In python 3.7 it is no longer [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/plistlib.html#plistlib.writePlistToBytes) and perhaps removed from `plistlib` library.

This means that `py2app` currently not yet compatible with Python 3.7. I found this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issues/242/py2app-incompatible-with-new-python-37), it was reported half a year ago and resolved a few days later. The resolution is: upgrade `py2app` to the latest version 0.15 with the following command :

```
pip3.7 install -U py2app
```

Verify version with

```
pip show py2app
```