# Fail to build a standalone executable file on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos-mojave, py2app, python-standalone

I want to make a standalone executable out of a script on a MacOS (10.14).

The script is `my_app.py` and has the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os.path
import csv
import pandas as pd

##1 open the file
f=open("path/to/original_file.txt", "r")

filedata = f.read()
##1

##1.1 replace the desired characters
filedata = filedata.replace("\\", ",")
filedata = filedata.replace("*", "")

with open("path/to/new_file.txt", 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
##1.1
```

and the following `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ["my_app.py"]
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    "argv_emulation": True,
    "packages": ["certifi"],
}
setup(
    app = APP,
    data_files = DATA_FILES,
    options = {"py2app": OPTIONS},
    setup_requires = ["py2app"]

)
```

Following the steps in a previous [SO questions with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847098/python-making-a-standalone-executable-file-on-macos), I entered sequentially the following commmands in `Terminal`:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv --system-site-packages
source venv/bin/activate
pip3.7 install -U py2app
cd /path/to/my_app.py
python setup.py py2app -A
```

However when I double click on `my_app.app` (which have just been created and which is located in `/Users/mymac/Documents/applications/myapp/dist`) I get the following error message in a pop-up window

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Does it have to do with the fact that there is no GUI framework in my app (like PyQT or Tkinter)?

Answer (score 0):

Mist likely you need to include a runtime library of some sort but another option is to create a script to run your app and then fix so that you can start your script from the Finder by double clicking it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125907/how-to-run-a-shell-script-in-os-x-by-double-clicking) for some alternative ways to do it.

The easiest way mentioned in the linked question is to give the script the extension `.command` then you shouldn’t need to do anything else.

The advantage of using a script is that it’s executed in the Terminal (in a shell) so you should have all the libraries etc available automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JoakimDanielson. I tried that solution before. If I'm not mistaken, this implies that you have a Python version installed on the machine you are running. I would like to make the app running on a computer without having to have Python installed (standalone)

Comment: @ecjb, Ah ok then you need to make sure you include the runtime and everything else in your app container. Unfortunately I can't help with that. Maybe something useful in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did check your link. `PyInstaller` seems to be a good alternative. I'm working on it and still have issues. I might post another question. What do you mean exactly by "runtime and everyting else": do you mean building the app around tkinter or PyQT?

Comment: I just meant anything that is needed by your app to run on its own. Sorry I am not a Phyton guy, I just happened to see this and thought about running as a script as a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

I could finally build a standalone by

- wrapping the application around a PyQt framework
- use `PyInstaller` to build the app

The my_app.py should look like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world")

        centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        centralWidget.setLayout(gridLayout)

        title = QLabel("Hello World from PyQt", self)
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        gridLayout.addWidget(title, 0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Then you cd the directory where the `my_app.py` resides. You then then run

```
PyInstaller my_app.py
```

This will create several directories: `__pycache__`, `build` and `dist`. Inside the `dist` there is another directory named `my_app`. In this directory there will be an executable named `my_app` (or referring to the original question, inside the path `path/to/dist/my_app/`) ==> double click on it and your app is running!